# Failed LQP audit: how to decide if an answer is spam?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19676196). The answer was supposedly spam, but I'm not sure how I should be coming to that conclusion.

[image: screenshot of failed audit]

Reasons why I thought the answer *wasn't* spam:

- The answer is on-topic: the question asked for "Load More Posts on Page Scroll" on Wordpress, and the asker is already using Ajax, so a Wordpress plugin that uses Ajax to lazy load content seems like an on-topic answer.
- The answerer has no affiliation with the linked plugin, as far as I can tell.
- The only other time this answerer has referred to "Ajax Load More" is in a question about that plugin (which is reasonable, as the answerer evidently uses this plugin).
- The linked plugin is a "real" product (as far as I can tell), not someone's hobby GitHub repo.
- The answerer is not a spam account and has real questions and answers.

After failing the audit I tried to come up with reasons why one might think it's spam, but none are particularly convincing to me (yet):

- The plugin is supposedly not free after one template. But are all paid resources automatically spam? Certainly not right, as long as they're helpful, relevant, and without conflict of interest? At least the answerer did a good job disclosing that fact (which I can't find evidence of, on the plugin's webpage).
- The asker comments that they need a solution without plugins. However, this requirement isn't in the question itself so I can't fault the answerer.
- The question was low quality and was deleted. But how does that affect the quality of the answer?
- The answer has some grammatical issues... but poor grammar isn't an indication of spam.

Could someone help me understand what makes this answer spam?

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361263/how-is-this-a-bad-answer) because that instance was primarily about "illegitimate self-promotion" (and secondarily about plagiarism). Neither of those issues apply to my question.

Comment: Actually the answer is **not** on-topic [as](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) "Questions asking us to *recommend* or find a *book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." Of course, that doesn't make the answer "spam" in itself.

Comment: The answer strongly suggested the question was off topic. In every single case like this, you need to view the question to determine the context, and to take the correct answer if the question *is* off topic, which is to vtc.

Comment: @Waylan I understand the **question** is not on-topic, and your quote refers to questions, not answers. Answering an off-topic question shouldn't make the answer automatically off-topic, and certainly not automatically spam.

Comment: @Will If the review was about the **question** then I certainly would have downvoted/vtc. But the review was about the **answer**. If someone answers an off-topic question, that doesn't make their answer spam.

Comment: yeah, get back to work! (cracks whip)

Comment: The problem wasn't the answer as much as it was the question. That's why you go check out the question. If you had done that, no failure of the audit. Don't put on blinders, keep your peepers open.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is this a bad answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361263/how-is-this-a-bad-answer)

Comment: Although the questions are similar, the answers clearly show that the cases were entirely different, thus I don't think that it would be a dupe.

Comment: Regardless of this being spam or not, I think "looks ok" was the wrong decision. Answers that just dump the name of some tool or library into the reader's face without demonstrating how it solves the problem are LQ and should be deleted as such. See e.g. [Recommending off-site resources when questions don't ask for it](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605)

Comment: It definitely does not look spam. It more look like link-only answer; definitely qualifies for deletion.

Comment: An answer that merely recommends a specific tool... should raise your suspicion. You may want to check other answers by the same answerer, and see if there is a pattern of promoting that tool. When in doubt, Skip the review.

Comment: I think a reverse dupe direction would be better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is this answer spam?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334123/how-is-this-answer-spam)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I'm sorry about this, I should have declined the spam flag before deleting the post, so that it won't be used as an audit.

I've disputed the flag and now it should no longer be an audit.

Answer (score 2):

You rightly failed the audit, but for the wrong reason.

The answer is not spam, but it is a bad answer... and bad answers very often appear on bad questions. So whenever you're reviewing an answer that "smells" bad, *always go and check the question it was posted against*. Otherwise you're not doing a proper review.

Take this as an opportunity to up your review game!

Comment: In fact I did read the question, which I did identify as poor. But when you come across an "not-great but ok" answer (in your opinion) to a bad question, do you suddenly have a worse opinion of the answer, and maybe recommend deletion of that answer? If not, please expand on _why_ you think the answer was a bad answer.