# Why was this answer deleted as spam and used as an audit question?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, low-quality-posts, spam, specific-answer

In the Low Quality Posts queue, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67568600/6689725) was used as an audit question, despite it obviously being a legitimate answer. Even worse, it was deleted by Community Bot as "spam or offensive content" 13 days ago, after being on the site for nearly 7 months.

[image: Screenshot of failed audit]

Edit to add:

apparently there are many differing opinions about this subject. [Here is a meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/527126) that states:

> Based on what we've decided in this question, I have updated the /faq on all sites to make it policy

Reading the policy that follows, we find this:

> Post good, relevant answers, and if they happen to be about your product, so be it

It sounds like self-promotion alone is not sufficient for a post to be considered spam.

Could there be some other reason to classify this post  as "Low Quality"?? My understanding (and please, correct me if this is wrong) is that the purpose of the LQP queue is to filter out posts that make no attempt to answer the question, or that are hopelessly unclear and cannot be salvaged. The post in question is unarguably an attempt to answer. Could it be better? Yes, absolutely. [But is it so bad that it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029/527126):

> does not address the question at all or is incomprehensible

??? The code snippet is easy to understand and the suggested solution is apparent enough. This answer is at least passable; it ticks all of the boxes. The only potential problem is this:

> you must disclose your affiliation with the product in your answers

Perhaps that alone is enough to justify deletion (even though it could be addressed through less aggressive means), but it's not clear from the post that the person answering is affiliated with the package being promoted. It's not even clear by following the link. It seems unlikely that this was the reason the question was originally removed.

So were left with the task of deciding if this answer is "Low Quality". Based on the content alone, it fails to meet the specifically enumerated criteria. And while it is self-promoting, that can only be discovered by clicking through and closely examining multiple external websites, all of which are commonly used to host legitimate software libraries. Finally, even if you succeed in uncovering this issue, nowhere does it say that it should be cause for deletion, nor is there an option listed in the "Recommend Deletion" dialog that is even remotely close to describing this situation.

---

### This is not a duplicate

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367613/failed-lqp-audit-how-to-decide-if-an-answer-is-spam) is being flagged as a duplicate, but it is not. That post is about an answer that was promoting commercial software, which is very clear just by reading the post. That is not the case here.

---

### Edit (Another Example, 2022-07-07):

I'll not create a new question for this, since it won't be well received, but this is another example of a very bad audit question:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32191796

The post is a legitimate attempt to answer the question. It is not a "link only", although it includes a link, and the linked site does indeed provide more information. The author may or may not be affiliated with the linked site, but the fact is that if the link were removed, the post would incontrovertibly be *not spam*. How can a link to a document that appears to be fully relevant and is in no way misleading change a valid answer to spam???

Comment: I believe "Community" will delete an answer if enough flags accumulate on it, no sentience required. Based on the context, this answer was probably spam deleted; it looks like a fine answer on the surface (which spam sometimes does) but maybe someone else has more context.

Comment: The community bot is attributed for deletion when spam/rude flags reach the 6 threshold or a single one from a moderator. What's not obvious here is that this was a bit of a mod clean up... There were 60+ of those answers saying: "You can try... <name of library>"...

Comment: ... and all of them had undisclosed affiliation.

Comment: Be always mindful whenever you see an external link on review. That should be a warning flag encouraging you to investigate more. You'd either find there is something fishy or not, or reveal the audit nature of the review task. But without that due diligence, you could be okaying spam.

Comment: It was used as an audit because it was deleted as spam. That part of the question really isn't a mystery. Cause -> effect.

Comment: @yivi the link was to https://pypi.org/project/simple-scheduler/ so nothing unreasonable or fishy.

Comment: @Z4-tier and if you go just one step further to the GitHub repo for that package, the owner of that repo has the same name as the answerer (i.e. that post is spam since it does not disclose affiliation)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat True, but I'm not sure if that's a level of investigation that should reasonably be expected from reviewers. If the username was on the linked page itself, then it's fine, but I wouldn't really say this is obvious enough. The answer itself was around for quite a while before anyone noticed.

Comment: @cigien In fact if hover over the authors name on the linked page I do see their name in the email there. Although I do agree it is a bit hidden.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat that is an unreasonable amount of detective work to ask for a post review, particularly for an audit. Even if we assume that what your suggesting is reasonable, your conclusion is very questionable. Just because the answer is the author doesn't immediately make the post spam. If Linus Torvalds came and said "hey Linux is great you should use it, here's how it solve your question ....[explanation]" would you delete it?

Comment: "despite it obviously being a legitimate answer." - It actually was obviously NOT a legitimate answer hence the reason it was deleted as spam by the community. It likely got attention which is the reason it wasn't deleted for 7 months.

Comment: @Nick I do not agree. That is directing traffic to what appears to be a personal website (or whatever "technoblogging.com" is). This question is about a post that directed to what appears to be a well maintained and documented software library on pypi.org. Very different.

Comment: What's the difference, exactly? Our spam/promotion rules don't distinguish between commercial and non-commercial software.

Comment: @Z4-tier That is not an unreasonable amount of detective work. I would at least check the author of the linked package for answers such as the one being discussed (Only a link to a package and code). If on the other hand one needs to check each contributor to that repo that might be unreasonable. And yes even if Linus Torvalds came and promoted Linux without disclosing their affiliation I would consider that spam (unless the question itself was about the tool promoted).

Comment: @CodyGray You are right, this meta post (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/527126) says promotion is allowable: "*Post good, relevant answers, and if they happen to be about your product, so be it*" and doesn't differentiate. The questions used to mark this as a duplicate though are not the same: both of them are incomplete answers posted as click bait to drive traffic to commercial websites to sell software. The post that is the topic of this question is different.

Comment: Yes, again, this isn't a good audit IMO. It looks like a reasonable answer, and the username doesn't match the author of the linked article, so I don't see how it's reasonable for someone to figure out the connection. This is all covered in the answer below, and there's not really any point in adding more examples of bad audits to this question. This is going to happen every now and then, since audits are automatically selected, so if you want to continue reviewing, I'd suggest either not getting upset about failing audits occasionally, or clicking through to the post for every review.

Comment: @cigien I appreciate the response. My intention in adding this new example is to at least note that it gives the impression that the bot is potentially a bit overzealous about which posts it removes. If humans can look at the post and not see the problem, should it really be removed automatically? I know it's driven by votes and flags, but it still suggests that perhaps there is room for improvement.

Comment: There's most certainly room for improvements to the audit system. What exactly these improvements should look like is not always clear, unfortunately. Here's a nice [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381963/) that goes over some of the possibilities to what changes could look like. Searching through Meta should yield some other discussions as well.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in the [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413540/why-was-this-answer-deleted-as-spam-and-used-as-an-audit-question#comment883067_413540)

> ... There were 60+ of those answers saying: "You can try... <name of library>" - Jon Clements

[and](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413540/why-was-this-answer-deleted-as-spam-and-used-as-an-audit-question#comment883068_413540)

> ... and all of them had undisclosed affiliation. - Zoe

So the answer was spam-deleted by a moderator, as the answer was one of many, linking to the same package, without disclosing affiliation. The audit system is automated, and this answer was selected by the system as it matched the necessary criteria.

---

That being said, I do think this is a poor audit. There's no indication in the answer that it's spam. The content of the answer is related to the question. When you see a link to an external site, you should investigate it, but in this case, the link is legitimate. Even investigating the user profile wouldn't reveal any affiliation. I would say the answer looks ok.

The only way to know that this was an audit is to look at it in the wild (i.e. on the main site). There are mixed feelings about whether this should be done for every review item. Personally, I think not; there shouldn't be any need to click through unless there's something fishy, and for this answer, I don't think there is. On the other hand, clicking through for every review means you'll never fail an audit, so that may well be a viable solution going forward.

Comment: 'There's no indication in the answer that it's spam." - That is actually the reason it's a good audit candidate to verify users can identify spam.

Comment: @SecurityHound But I don't feel this is at all obvious spam, i.e. I wouldn't expect the average user to realize, even with investigation, that the user is affiliated. It would also be nearly impossible to determine that it's a pattern, if the other posts are deleted. I'm not sure review audits are supposed to be this subtle. There's another example where there was a spam wave that was only obvious when you know it's spam, and it generated a lot of bad audits, which were removed by mods. This one is similarly subtle IMO.

Comment: @SecurityHound The post in question is recommending an open source library that the post's author happened to write. It's not an attempt to push commercial software. Would you call it spam if the post had simply pasted the full source code of the library? The poster should have disclosed their affiliation, but that also does not make it spam.

Comment: Obviously, what made it spam was the op "spamming it" across 60+ questions... but that can't be seen from review or even from following the link to the post. Just another example of why the audit system shouldn't use mod handled posts for audits.

Comment: @Z4-tier - Besides the fact the author did not disclose the fact, they wrote the library, which I would argue is by itself enough justification to at least flag the answer for moderator attention. The author of the library spammed the Stack Overflow community, with dozens of answers with a link to their library, in order to promote their open source library. **Does not really matter if it's open source.**

Comment: Your answer hits the nail on the head. In a perfect world is should not be necessary to click through to every question/answer to do a review. But in reality, I really recommend that you do unless you like the look of that "STOP!" message you get after an unfairly failed audit. The annoyance/upset or even outrage IS preventable, but it is not going to help to demand change after every failure. It simply isn't going to be changed, unless someone has some wicked AI trick that can be implemented with greater success rates than pure randomness.