# In "Low Quality Posts" is it required to cross-check external links with profile pages to identify Improper Self Promotion?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, spam, specific-answer, specific-audit

In the "Low Quality Answers" queue, how much cross-checking effort is required to verify that an external link in an otherwise-valid answer isn't [improper self-promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)?

In the "Low Quality Answers" queue I was presented with the following [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30721414):

[image: Boostrap DateTimePicker show time only]

It looked like a legit answer, but to make sure it wasn't copied from a previous answer I clicked over to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70507711/3744182) -- and found it had been deleted by "Community [BOT]" with  one downvote, likely indicative of a single "Spam" flag cast by a Mod:

[image]

But why is this spam?  The Demo link refers to a Q&A page on a linked site and it seems the answer was taken from the answer there, so maybe there's a violation of https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing here and the link should have been labeled e.g. *Source* rather than *Demo*.  However, as pointed out in [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415049/why-was-this-boostrap-datetimepicker-answer-deleted-as-spam-by-community-bot?noredirect=1#comment887577_415049) by [MisterMiyagi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5349916/mistermiyagi) the same site is listed as the **home page for the author of the post**, which is apparently what qualifies as the post as illegal self-promotion and thus delete-worthy.

So my question is, is this the sort of thing that should be caught in a Low Quality Answers audit?  The poster's name isn't mentioned on the linked page (I did check that), so one would either need to spot a pattern of such answers, or, in Low Quality Posts, always manually cross-check external links in the post being reviewed against the profile page of the poster for signs of self-promotion. But is this something that reviewers are expected to do?

Looking at the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70507711/timeline) (screen shot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqf1T.png) it seems answer was used as an audit once before -- and that reviewer failed the audit.  So I'm not the only reviewer tripped up by this.

(Note this question was edited based on [feedback in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415049/why-was-this-boostrap-datetimepicker-answer-deleted-as-spam-by-community-bot?noredirect=1#comment887584_415049).)

Comment: The link in that answer is listed by the author as their homepage, but the answer does not make this clear at all. Looks like a clear case of failing to disclose the author's affiliation. ["However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - OK.  That's a definite violation of https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing then.  Still not sure this answer is appropriate for an audit.  I always click through to the original question when doing a "Low quality post" review -- but is it now necessary to click through to the author's page to cross-check affiliations against links in the question when doing a review?

Comment: "*For that matter, was there enough evidence for the Community bot to automatically delete it as spam?*" -> Yes, definitely; as this is not the only infraction by the user. When you see "deleted by community bot" with less than 6 downvotes, that means a moderator manually intervened, and deleted the answer as spam. As to whether it's a reasonable audit, I've [opined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413540) on a similar case before, which might be relevant.

Comment: @cigien - Thanks for the explanation, I had not known that.  I had thought that, when a mod intervened, the mod would also be listed as among the deleters of the post.

Comment: Mods can (and usually do) flag as spam just like regular users, and it works the same way - the flagger's name isn't shown - except that mods' flags are binding and delete it instantly.

Comment: They had 5 posts, all of which were unaffiliated links to that website. Prior to that, they had 3 answers linking you a youtube channel that links to the same domain (happened in 2017, the answers weren't deleted as spam at the time). [1](//stackoverflow.com/a/70503508/6296561), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70507778/6296561), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70505359/6296561), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70505306/6296561), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70507711/6296561). The public data alone tells you what you need to know though; undisclosed affiliation

Comment: Your comment "*but is it now necessary to click through to the author's page to cross-check affiliations against links in the question when doing a review?*" should really be the focus of this question, as the issue of whether it's actually spam has been confirmed, and it being chosen as an audit is an automatic process. I'd suggest editing the question to focus on that.

Comment: @cigien - question edited as per your feedback.

Comment: *"In "Low Quality Posts" is it required to cross-check external links with profile pages to identify Improper Self Promotion?"* - I mean... why not? In every queue where you're reviewing content with a link/recommendation/tool/etc. you should be checking if it's spam

Comment: It should be also be noted that spam in the LQP queue is _not_ a reason to recommend deletion/delete. Spam in the LQP queue should be handled with a spam flag from outside the queue and then skipped (as per [the basic workflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029/684990))

Comment: @Nick - *"In "Low Quality Posts" is it required to cross-check external links with profile pages to identify Improper Self Promotion?" - I mean... why not?* No strong reason why not -- other than not having been told to do it and not having thought to do it.  Which is why I'm asking this question.

Comment: Why should you check this? The low quality post review queue only asks you "identify, then improve or delete low quality answers". Self promotion doesn't play into the quality of the post, so long as it's relevant to the question asked. (If I'm curl creator and I answer a curl question, I don't need to tell so)

Answer (score 5):

My process for links looks something like the following. This probably seems overwhelming, but it usually goes really fast since the majority of links get crossed off quickly.

#### Direct Checks

1. Does the link point to an **official resource** or **recognized site** specifically associated with the technology in question (such as official documentation)? If so, move to next link.
2. Does the link point to a **well-known code sharing site** (e.g., JSFiddle or Gist) with code not in the question? Does the post *rely* on that code? If so, flag as e.g. *NAA*. Otherwise, move to next link.
3. Does the target page contain a **byline, user name, and/or unique avatar**? Do any of those correlate with the author's? If so (and it's unattributed), flag as spam.

#### Indirect Checks

The three direct checks cover the vast majority of links. After that, I move onto the more time-consuming, indirect checks:

4. Does the page contain an **about page, social links, or contributors manifest** that correlate with the author's name?

   > *Note:* This may require clicking through to e.g. source code for a library. This can be hard to spot if they're just using e.g. an import statement or package reference.
5. Does the site appear in the **contributor's profile**, or is it affiliated with their employer? This obviously covers the case you're talking about.
6. Does the site appear in any of their **recent posts**? Often, there will be a pattern of relying on a specific site—and sometimes one of the posts will even acknowledge the affiliation.

> *Note:* In any of these cases, I flag for *moderator attention* with a link to the evidence that it's spam (e.g., the profile, about page, GitHub contributors page, &c.).

#### Warning Signs

As part of this, I also rely on some heuristics for weighing the probability of self-promotion. These include:

1. Does the page look like a **canned blog template**? Are the social links, about page, &c. personalized? Is the username e.g., "Admin"? If it's just stock messaging, that's a warning sign.
2. Does the target page contain a **date posted**? That might include commits on GitHub. If it's from the last week, or it's a blog post without a date, that's a warning sign. (Sometimes, the blog entry was posted minutes before a Stack Overflow answer.)
3. Is there an **engagement metric**, such as downloads for a library, stars on GitHub, or comments on a blog? If so, and there's little to no engagement, that's a warning sign that this is a personal site.
4. Does it relate to **cryptocurrencies**? I'm only half joking here. I've noticed a lot of suspicious links (as well as  new contributors answering one another's posts with the same links) and references related to emerging cryptocurrency tags.

In those cases, I might dig in more, or I might flag for a moderator if it seems *really* suspicious. But, usually, I'll just leave a comment like:

> Please be sure to read [Stack Overflow's self-promotion policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) when referencing your own content.

And then skip. That's my way of saying, "I'm really suspicious, but I don't have enough evidence to flag this."