# Unacceptable answer -- but why?

Tags: support, late-answers

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/31730627) is was flagged by [Community Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) as "spam or offensive content." It contains polite language:

> Well, Mr.ajb has resolved and pointed out the error in your code.
>
> Coming to the second part of the code, that is, converting a string with letters to decimal integer below is code for that,

...a brief description, code that certainly seems relevant to the task at hand, and a link to a site describing how to solve a similar problem. The response I got on reviewing it looks bizarre to me: "It is abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful." What's going on here? If deletion was appropriate, why? If not, should a bot be making such decisions, or how is there oversight, or how should I have reported a problem with the bot?

Comment: Link at the end is same as the one in the review reported here: [Was this audit wrong or am I missing something?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417931)

Comment: BTW, the bot didn't "take a decision". The user account was nuked by a diamond moderator or a staff member and with it all its contributions. Community takes ownership of that simply because there is no other user to assign it to.

Comment: Presumably due to link spam, in this case to `www DOT flowerbrackets DOT com`? I think a common technique is to plagiarise answers to similar questions to make it seem legitimate. Have they started employing [GPT-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPT-3) for it?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: the spam for this account predates GPT-3.

Comment: The comments are informative. I still don't know how this could be useful for auditing whether a reviewer is paying attention when vetting late answers; it seems the information a reviewer could use to determine it is spam is not available.

Comment: I *think* you are supposed to catch link spam. Aren't there a lot of meta questions about this? A similar meta question (with even more subtle link spam): *[Detecting punctuation link-spam in LQ-reviews / failed audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322434/)*

Comment: It would really suck if mankind is wiped out by an AI created to generate spam.

Comment: @user4581301 unfortunately we don't need AI for that.

Comment: No, we definitely don't. But getting exterminated by a Spam AI is adding insult to annihilation. Right up there with getting snuffed out by Office Assistant Clippy.

Comment: "It contains polite language" at least that thing should have moved you to edit the post to remove it. Salutations, taglines and other kind of "politeness" have no place on posts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer